# Email should NOT be sent when NO data in the selected sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which pulls data from a defined tab name 'Master' in Google sheet, which is then sending an email triggering at a specific time.

My problem is I don't want script to send blank email if the table in 'Master' is empty. Script should stop sending email.

Otherwise keeps triggering email on mentioned time.
Can anyone please share their insight on this.

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var recipient = 'email@gmail.com'
  var subject = 'Stock Report'
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  var schedRange = sheet.getRange("A1:L21"); 

  var body = '<div style="text-align:center;display: inline-block;font-family: arial,sans,sans-serif">'
  body += '<H1>'+ 'Low Stock Report ' +'</H1>';
  body += '<H2>'
  body += getHtmlTable(schedRange);
  body += '</div>'; 
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "Requires HTML", {htmlBody:body}) 
  //End sendNotification

}
```

Comment: Do you expect the table `schedRange` to be either completely full or completely empty of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to check if the table is not empty

- If your table is `var schedRange = sheet.getRange("A1:L21");` you can check either its empty by [retrieving its values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and send it only in case a non-empty value is found.
- You can implement a boolean variable  - as soon as the first non-empty value is found in the table - it will be set to true and an email will be sent.

Sample:

```
function sendEmail() {
  ...
  var schedRange = sheet.getRange("A1:L21"); 
  var values = schedRange.getValues();
  var send = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++){
      var value = values[i][j];
      if (value !="" && value !=" "){
        return send = true;
      }
    }
  }
  if (send == true){   
    var body = '<div style="text-align:center;display: inline-block;font-family: 
    ...
    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "Requires HTML", {htmlBody:body}) 
  }
}
```

---

You can also do something like this:

```
  var schedRange = sheet.getRange("A1:L21"); 
  var values = schedRange.getValues();
  if (values.flat(2).length>0) {
    //Send
    var body = '<div style="text-align:center;display: inline-block;font-family: 
    ...
    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "Requires HTML", {htmlBody:body}) 
  }
```

Thanks to the fact that `flat()` will make a 2D array into a simple array, removing empty elements, we can use it to basically remove all blank values from the array, effectively checking if it's empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

After applying sample code I am not getting email, I have tried both ways with and without data in Master Sheet but no email.I am not sure if i am doing the right way.

Sample:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var recipient = 'alislife87@gmail.com'
  var subject = 'Stock Report'
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  var schedRange = sheet.getRange("A1:L21"); 
  var values = schedRange.getValues();
  var send = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++){
      var value = values[i][j];
      if (value !="" && value !=""){
        return send = true;
      }
    }
  }
  if (send == true){   
    var body = '<div style="text-align:center;display: inline-block;font-family: 
    arial,sans,sans-serif">'
    body += '<H1>'+ 'Low Stock Report ' +'</H1>';
    body += '<H2>'
    body += getHtmlTable(schedRange);
    body += '</div>';
    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "Requires HTML", {htmlBody:body})  
  }
}
```